# Android App/AVD problems

Tags: android, emulation, buzztouch

This is my 1st attempt at an app - i'm a novice at this so please be patient!

I've created a basic app using buzztouch. I've downloaded the sourcecode and created a project from an existing source in Eclipse. This worked great for me last week until yesterday and today when I made a few changes and now can't get it to run in my AVD. It seems to be constantly stuck on this:

```
Success!

[2012-02-14 11:47:07 - My APP] Starting activity com.v1_4.B5281B33D837B06A96214D94.com.Act_Home on device emulator-5554

[2012-02-14 11:47:08 - My APP] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.v1_4.B5281B33D837B06A96214D94.com/.Act_Home }
```

And my AVD is on this:

[image]

This "only take a moment" has been the same for almost 2 hours now! I'm guessing there's something wrong, rather than it is still downloading? I've tried it on a 2.3.3 AVD and a Google API level 10 AVD. I'm sure it's something simple that i'm not doing (or that I am doing incorrectly!!)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your SDK manager and check which all versions of Android SDK you have.
2. Open your AVD manager and delete the existing AVD
3. Create a new AVD with the existing SDK version on your system.

Comment: Ok, i've tried that - but doesn't seem to have made much of a difference.
I did have this working a few days ago and made changes to the app only through buzztouch.

I've tried to recompile the source code also a few times but still no joy
Any other ideas

By the way, the android version is 2.3.3!

Thanks